# How to save drop down list selected value of Item template in database on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please find image. Here's my whole code, I wanted save each row on save button click. I'm able to get value from cell 0 and cell 1 but unable to get value from cell 2 , where I have drop down list selected value.I'm getting default value "Ignore" instead of selected item. So how do I get selected value of drop down list ?

```
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" 
           OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound" Width="544px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />       
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Mapping" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" style="font-size: medium; font-family: Cambria" Width="300px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save" 
           style="font-size: medium; font-family: Cambria" BorderStyle="Groove" 
           height="32px"  Width="116px" onclick="Save_Click" />
    </div>





 private void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    connection();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select top 0 * from  F3_BC_Product_Mapping_Data", con);
    con.Open();
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();        
    adapter.Fill(ds, "mytable");
    int j = 1;
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)) });
    foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(j,column.ColumnName);
        j++;
    } 
    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();
    con.Close();

}

  protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddlMap = (e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Session["data"];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ddlMap.Items.Add(dt.Columns[i].Caption.ToString());
        }
        ddlMap.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Ignore"));
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

```
 protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView2.Rows)
    {

        string cell_1_Value = GridView2.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
        string cell_2_Value = GridView2.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        string cell_3_Value = ((DropDownList)gr.FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling BindGrid?

Comment: My understanding is, that you should initialize selectable values in `Page_Init` in order to enable loading of selected value from the available options. However, I didn't work with ASP.Net for a while now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting default value then you must see binding code. I think you haven't use `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` before binding and setting default value in drop down. Try to change `OnRowDataBound` as below.

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && !Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList ddlMap = (e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Session["data"];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ddlMap.Items.Add(dt.Columns[i].Caption.ToString());
        }
        ddlMap.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Ignore"));
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I'm still getting value as "Ignore"

Comment: Unlikely. OP would receive a null reference exception then because FindControl would not find anything. I believe you can run FindControl on the row to find controls inside this row no problem

Comment: @Andrei This is not going to give null ref exception because dropdown is inside cell. OP witnessed the same in his comment to this answer.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Session["data"];
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        BindGrid();       
    }

Comment: I'm fetching values from database to fill column Name and fetching column name of another table saved in session and loading drop down list.

Comment: @Imad i tried updated code . Now I'm getting empty string instead of "Ignore"

Comment: Are dropdown values vanishing after button click?

Comment: @Imad no they are not. Values are the same which I have selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126001/discussion-between-user6774270-and-imad).

Comment: @Imad My mistake , after clicking button ,Selected values were gone and Default value is there..I.e. "ignore"